# Active directory user sessions are not appearing under the "Collections/Connections" in Remote Desktop Services

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, remote-desktop-services

I am currently using Windows Server 2012 r2 and I am trying to setup RDP shadow services on my services to be able to remotely connect to current user sessions who are on the domain, I set up all the correct GPO and permissions for remote desktop however the the user session never appear on under collections when I am sure there are users connected to the domain. The only Users that show users who are locally logged in to the server. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it doesn't work that way.  What you seem to want, doesn't actually exist as a Windows feature.

You can only shadow sessions on RDS servers.  You can't shadow sessions on random Windows workstations simply because they are connected to the domain.

With group and pro/enterprise licenes on all your windows desktops, you can enable RDP access, but you cannot shadow an existing session.  You can setup [remote assistance](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20remote%20assistance) through group policy, which is somewhat similar to a shadow connection.